# What is XDG_RUNTIME_DIR?

Tags: command-line, sudo, evince

While I was trying to open **Evince** from Command line, it's giving me an error

```
neo@Muhammad:~$ sudo evince

No protocol specified

** (evince:4164): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

How to troubleshoot this problem ?

Comment: Tell us more about your operating system.

Comment: Note that it's not a good idea to run `evince` or any other program that's commonly used to open *untrusted* files as `root`. Untrusted PDF files are maybe in top 3 for potential security attacks against your system.

Answer (score 99):

### First things first: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

To answer your first question, *"What is XDG_RUNTIME_DIR?"*, it is an environment variable that is set automatically when you log in. It tells any program you run where to find a user-specific directory in which it can store small temporary files. Note that [`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables) is set by [`pam_systemd`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/pam_systemd.8.html), so it is not actually related to ***X*** (running programs graphically), which is the problem you seem to be having.

### How to troubleshoot

Your second question, *"How to troubleshoot this problem?"* is a very good one. That means you're interested in not only *what* the fix is, but also *how* to figure it out on your own. To start, look at the first error messages first. In particular, searching for `No protocol specified` or `WARNING **: Could not open X display`, should show you that the problem is with ***X*** (also called *The X Windowing System*) which is how graphical programs are shown on your screen. Knowing that should raise many troubleshooting questions in your mind.

### X DISPLAY

Your next question might be, what is this *"X display"* that evince can't open? A "display" is the address for your screen.<sup>[*]</sup> Any program that wants to write to your screen has to know the address. You can see what your X display is by checking the DISPLAY environment variable:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

And you can check what `sudo` thinks your DISPLAY is by typing:

```
sudo -s
echo $DISPLAY
exit
```

If it doesn't show anything, then that's the problem. (See fix below).

## XAUTHORITY

But, what if that's not the problem and the `DISPLAY` is set correctly in `sudo`? Then you might wonder, does ***X*** have some sort of permissions that prevent other users from writing on my display? If you thought that, you'd be right, ***X*** has two main authorization methods: `xauth` and `xhost`. The most commonly used one today is [`xauth`(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xauth.1.html) which uses the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable. Again, let's check if it is properly set in `sudo`:

```
echo $XAUTHORITY
sudo -s
echo $XAUTHORITY
exit
```

If `XAUTHORITY` is pointing to a file in your home directory for you, but it's blank when you run `sudo`, then that's the problem.

## FIX: Save the Environment Variables

So, what's the fix? If either the `DISPLAY` or the `XAUTHORITY` environment variables aren't getting saved across the `sudo`, you can tell [`sudo`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html) to preserve the environment by using the `-E` option, like so:

```
sudo -E evince
```

### A better way: env_keep

You might well ask, Wait, if `-E` makes everything magically work, then why isn't it the default for `sudo`? The answer is that it is a potential security hazard. Environment variables affect the way programs work and you don't want them all being exported from a user account to the root. The "correct" way to do it is to add the line `Defaults env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"` to the [`sudoers`(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) file using [`visudo`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/visudo.8.html). You can check what environment variables sudo preserves by running:

```
sudo sudo -V
```

(Yes, you type `sudo` twice). I recommend putting the line not in the default sudoers file (`/etc/sudoers`), but in a local file that won't get overwritten when you upgrade your system. You can do that like so:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/local
```

### But wait, what if none of the above works?

I think this is a fairly thorough answer, but if you're still having trouble, there's one other thing I'd suggest. You can use [`xhost`(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xhost.1.html) to grant access to a specific user on the local host (your machine) like so,

```
xhost si:localuser:root
```

In this case, we're specifying `root` as the username, since that's the account that `sudo` runs programs as.

---

<sup>[*]</sup>: *Q:* I've only got one screen, so why does an X display need an "address"? *A:* It's because ***X*** can work not only on your machine, but over the internet. With ***X***, it's easy to run programs on your machine that show up on other internet hosts and programs on other hosts that appear on your screen (assuming you give them permission).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I'm sure there's at least something new in your answer for every user. (For me: how to grant access to X to a specific user, which is better than issuing `xhost +` to allow universal access.)

Comment: This is an exemplary answer! You are a hacker after my own heart. I've been using *nix since 1995 and I learned a lot from this. Thank you, friend.

Comment: @MuhammadIllyas for pete's sake, EXCEPT THIS ANSWER!!! why is it that the very best answers are unaccepted??

Comment: This solution indeed resolve the OP's real question. However, it does not actually resolve "error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment". For that, you need to investigate the PAM rules.

Answer (score 7):

`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is an environment variable set in your X Windows context, so that programs can find things. You (`neo`) have set up the graphics context.

By trying to run `evince` as `root`, you have entered the condition where a user (`root`) is trying to access another user's (`neo`) display. This is regarded as a Bad Thing.

If you decide you MUST run a graphical editor as `root`, read `man gksudo`
and make use of `gksudo`.

Comment: interesting comment. Do you happen to know then how i could to something like this ? `journalctl -b -p err | wl-copy` it reports `Failed to connect to a Wayland server` which makes sens, but sounds dumb from User POV.

Comment: A quick note. The variable has absolutely nothing to do with X Windows context. It is initialized regardless whether X is installed. It is set by systemd and defined in XDG Base Directory Specification here https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html.